# How to simulate an response error with AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm having to deal with one situation: I have created an endpoint on my application that is using SDK v1 of AWS, this endpoint should delete multiple objects on a bucket and return the response.

```
Request: [objectName1, ojbectName2, .... objectNameN]
Response: 
          { 
            objectDeleted: [objectName1, objectName2, ... ObjectNameN],
            error: [ { name: objectName, errorMsg } , ... ]
          }
```

So, I'm using the method .deleteObjects of the S3 Client, but i can't simulate the objects with error, so i can't implementate the error list in my code, actually I've used a DTO and have mocked the return of my delete method, but when using aws I don't know how it will behave when an error happen, for example, if i'm deleting a list of objects and when the operation is occurring throw one error, the operation will stop, the objects first tagged as to be deleted will be deleted? If someone can help me with this trouble.

Comment: The documentation for DeleteObjects is not clear but you can probably test this by simply testing with IAM permissions that allow you delete some test objects but not all test objects.

Comment: I'll try to change permissions for each object to try this, thank you, hope this might help me

Comment: A simple role that allows you to delete prefix1/* but not prefix2/* and then issue a DeleteObjects request for a couple of objects under each prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a policy that Deny all objects deletion with an prefix "deny-*" and worked fine for me.